# NHibernate sessions using Castle Windsors LifestylePerWebRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, castle-windsor

Using Castle Windsor as my IoC container and NHibernate I have the following registration:

```
Component.For<ICustomSessionFactory>()
  .ImplementedBy<MsSql2008SessionFactory>().LifeStyle.Singleton,

Component.For<ISession>()
 .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<ICustomSessionFactory>()
     .OpenSession()).LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
```

Where `ISession` is an `NHibernate.ISession`.

This works great. My question is regarding the closing of my `ISession`.

Will Castle Windsor deal with the closing of my session or do I need to close it myself some how?

I see in the [documentation](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Seven-Lifestyles.ashx) that:

> Therefore Windsor knows when to release the per web request objects
>   and it will do it without requiring any action from you.

Does this mean that the closing of the session is handled by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, windsor will close the session for you.

You can also log all the container info:

```
        void ConfigureContainer()
        {
            _container = new WindsorContainer();

            _container.Install(new LoggerInstaller());
            _logger = _container.Resolve<ILogger>();

#if DEBUG
            _container.Kernel.ComponentRegistered += (k, h) => _logger.Debug(String.Format("Registered {0} - {1}/{2}", k, h.ComponentModel.ComponentName.Name, h.ComponentModel.Implementation.FullName));
            _container.Kernel.ComponentDestroyed += (k, h) => _logger.Debug(String.Format("Destoyed {0} - ", k.ComponentName.Name));
#endif
            _container.Install(new ContainerInstaller());
            _container.Install(new NHibernateInstaller());
            _container.Install(new ValidationInstaller());
        }
```